# Can't get messages which wasn't marked read by myself. Not count

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have list of chats.
I want to get messages from chats.
I want to get only those messages which were not marked as read by me.
I didn't find any parameters or functions which can show if the message was read. Neither any parameter for get dialog functions.

I found only count:

```
async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
    dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
    dialog.unread_count
    dialog.unread_mentions_count
```

I tried parse dialogs and looked. But found nothing:

```
async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
    async for message in client.iter_messages(dialog):
        print(message.stringify())
```

Also got nothing in API.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.